# Dropdown form with submit button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a dropdown with links in them, when I select the option it will go to the page, but I want to use a button instead but not sure how to change the javascript to make this happen:

```
   <select name="form" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"class="form-control">
          <option>Choose a Service</option>
          <option value="http://www.google.com">Option 1</option>
          <option value="http://www.google.com">Option 2</option>
          <option value="http://www.google.com">Option 3</option>
          <option value="http://www.google.com">Option 4</option>
          <option value="http://www.google.com">Option 5</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: What you want is unclear. Could you please post an example of what you would want it to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting `location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value` in `unChange`, move it to a button `onClick` event:

```
<select id="dropdown" name="form" class="form-control">
  <option>Choose a Service</option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com">Option-1</option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com">Option-2</option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com">Option-3</option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com">Option-4</option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com">Option-5</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Go!" onClick='location = document.getElementById("dropdown").options[document.getElementById("dropdown").selectedIndex].value'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <select id="dd" name="form">
      <option>Choose a Service</option>
      <option value="http://www.google.com">Option 1</option>
      <option value="http://www.google.com">Option 2</option>
      <option value="http://www.google.com">Option 3</option>
      <option value="http://www.google.com">Option 4</option>
      <option value="http://www.google.com">Option 5</option>
    </select>

    <button onClick="launchPage" >

    <script>
      var launchPage = function() {
        var e = document.getElementById("dd");
        var url = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        window.open(url);
      };
    </script>
```

Comment: This worked as well, I am not sure which one I should use though. Is it just a matter of preference or maybe convention?

Comment: Mostly preference. A lot of people would choose this one over the other because it is easier to maintain as your code expands. First one is the quick and dirty way, this one is the longer and cleaner maintenance way